# How to make the image also have rounded corners?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make the image's corner also be rounded but when I apply `border-radius` on the div, the image corner dosen't change at all.

```css
#bredband {
  height: 330px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #9099A2;
  margin: 20px;
  float:left;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bredband">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Corinex_Router.jpg" width="300" height="200">
  <h3>Bredband</h3>
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I want the whole box to be rounded also the image, now you see that only the bottom part is rounded.

Comment: I am unable to replicate the image you have provided. Please provide all of the CSS you are currently using in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to your `#bredband` selector. That should clip the top corners.